# Using SendKeys function on an an external program

Tags: c#, sendkeys

I have the following code to send keys

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process[] copyFrom = Process.GetProcessesByName("UI.Main");
        Process myApp = Process.GetCurrentProcess();

        if (copyFrom.Length > 0)
            SetForegroundWindow(copyFrom[0].MainWindowHandle);
        else
            Process.Start("UI.Main.exe");

        SendKeys.Send("^c");
        SendKeys.Send("{DOWN}");
        SendKeys.Send("^v");

        SetForegroundWindow(myApp.MainWindowHandle);

        myString = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Text);
        MessageBox.Show(myString);
    }
```

This code works fine if I use a different application like notepad, MS Word or Excel or whatever however it does not work with my application.

Its a full screen application with no close, minimize or maximize button.
If I press a button on the keyboard it works however it does not respond to any button with the SendKeys function.

Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: Did you try `SendKeys.Send("bla");` without any other stuff? So did you try  it without any `SetForeGroundWindow`  code? Because this should actually work. Could you provide the exact code you tried with your application? Or did you just change the name of the application to yours?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that. it still does not respond

Comment: And you're sure the window was focused at that time? Did you try something like `Focus();` before already?